# numpy - simple way to check if object is numpy float array

Tags: numpy, types

## Question

Is there a better/simpler way to check if an object is numpy float array?

```
import numpy as np
isinstance(x, np.ndarray) and issubclass(x.dtype.type, np.floating)
```

Comment: `x.dtype` is sufficent to determine Numpy object's type.

Comment: According to the latest release notes (1.20), `isinstance(dtype, np.dtype).` is correct dtype test form.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html#isinstance-dtype-np-dtype-and-not-type-dtype-is-not-np-dtype